# Sorting Ascending an ArrayList of objects as they're passed to a class

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I need to sort teams by record as they're passed to an ArrayList. I have tried a few solutions and none have worked. I don't under stand why this one won't work however.

```
public void add(Team x) {


    if(!teams.isEmpty()){

            for(int i=0;i<teams.size();i++){
             if (x.compareTo(teams.get(i))==1){
                 teams.add(i,x);
             }
             if(i==teams.size()-1){
                 teams.add(x);
             }else{
                 break;
             }

         } 

    }else{
        teams.add(x);
    }
}
```

This is the compareTo method:

```
public int compareTo(Team y){
    int n  = this.record()- y.record();
    if(n<=0){
        return n;
    }else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The code gets stuck in an infinite loop after adding the first two elements and I can't figure out why. Is there a way to make this method work or to sort the list by record.

Comment: Is there the possibility that your record method somehow calls comlareTo?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to maintain is a dynamic sorted set. This can be done using the `TreeSet` class in JAVA. All the data you enter, it will be always sorted. It is essentially a Binary Search Tree and insertions take *O(Log(n))* time. Here is how you can do it. The tutorial for TreeSet is [here](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/treeset-class-in-java-with-example/):

```
TreeSet<Team> teams=new TreeSet<Team>(new Comparator<Team>() //with custom comparator
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Team o1, Team o2)
    {
        int n  = o1.record()- y.record();
        if(n<=0){
            return n;
        }else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
});
```

```
//The method to add data should be
public void add(Team x)
{
    teams.add(x);
}
```

Finally, you can convert the set to an ArrayList simply using `ArrayList<Team> data=new ArrayList<Team>(teams);`

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `compareTo` as with `Comparable`, i.e. return `0` for equal elements, negative number if `x` is smaller, and positive if `x` is larger (given `x.compareTo(y);`).

Then your loop becomes

```
for(int i = 0;i < teams.size();i++) {
    if(x.compareTo(teams.get(i)) < 0)
        continue;
    // Insert into middle
   return;
}
// If we got here, insert at the end
```